# Why is my ansible task failing to build my docker image when using containers.podman.podman_image

Tags: ansible, podman

I am trying to use the containers.podman.podman_image module to build a new image for my application.
I can't tell why the new image isnot being created. All I get back from ansible is that the step has a return of "ok".

So this time I added the register: results to the build task and printed the results using debug.  I still can't see what is going wrong.

My build task looks like:

```yaml
- name: Build a Docker formatted image for the ldapserver
  containers.podman.podman_image:
    name: ldapserver
    path: "{{ srcdir }}"
    build:
      format: docker
      cache: no
      force_rm: yes
  register: results
```

The results I get from the debug task are:

```
TASK [buildImage : Print the results of the build step] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "actions": [],
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "image": {},
        "podman_actions": [
            "/usr/bin/podman image ls ldapserver:latest --format json",
            "/usr/bin/podman inspect ldapserver:latest --format json"
        ],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the ansible task that runs the `podman` commands (in case the problem is with that task rather than the build process)...or confirm that you get the same results when running the `podman ls ...` command manually on the command line. The `inspect` command should **fail** if the image doesn't exist, but your output shows the task is successful.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. The image already exists and Ansible returns OK. If you want the image to be built regardless of its existance, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/containers/podman/podman_image_module.html#parameter-force

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the container image already existing.

You can either remove the image before running your task:

```bash
podman rmi ldapserver
```

or you can force Ansible to build the image even if it exists:

```yaml
- name: Build a Docker formatted image for the ldapserver
  containers.podman.podman_image:
    name: ldapserver
    path: "{{ srcdir }}"
    force: true
    build:
      format: docker
      cache: no
      force_rm: yes
  register: results
```

I would recommend the first, since it's good practice to keep your playbooks idempotent.